# How to convert a string to int in the LINQ where condistion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am writing some `LINQ` which will convert a `string` to `int` when the string is not null or empty, as follows

```
(from job in db.klpm_job
 join project in db.klpm_project on job.ProjectID equals project.ProjectID
 join client in db.klpm_client on project.ClientID equals client.ClientID
 join status in db.klpm_status on job.JobStatusID equals status.StatusID
 where job.StatusCode != "INA" && job.JobStatusID == JobStatusID
  && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClientID) ? project.ClientID == int.Parse(ClientID) : true)
                             select new
                             {
                                 job,                                     
                             });
```

now the problem is when i am running this query. It is giving me exception that

```
    LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' 
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How to solve this.

Comment: @xanatos I want to know the method which will convert in to int inside the LINQ not outside

Comment: From the linked response: *Sadly at least Linq-to-Entities doesn't have any cast method. You can obtain something similar by using a user defined function, but it is a little complex.*